# Your branch and 'origin/new_ci3' have diverged

Tags: git

I am sorry for asking this basic question. Any help would be appreciated. I have undone the last commit and I got changes in the staged state then I got this message when I checked git status.What to do next? Should i push it?

**Your branch and 'origin/new_ci3' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)**

Comment: What does "undone the last commit" mean? What _exactly_ did you do?

Comment: $ git reset --soft HEAD~1 using this command i have undone the last commit.

Comment: OK, so after a `reset --soft` you are in a very precarious position. You now have some uncommitted changes in your working tree and in your index. You cannot proceed at all until you do something about that. You could of course commit — but that is exactly what you "undid" with `reset --soft`, so if you did that, you would be going round in circles. So clearly the first question to ask yourself is why on earth you did the `reset --soft` and where you were intending to go from there. Then go there (though I cannot imagine where "there" would be.) Then let's talk again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of what is on origin and replace it with what you have locally:

```
git push new_ci3 --force-with-lease
```

but make sure you are happy to delete what is on origin

On the other hand, if you want to replace what is on origin, but have a record of what used to be there, I like this one:

```
git merge origin/new_ci3 -sours
# make a commit message like 'replacing old history with new history'
git push origin new_ci3 # now force push needed
```

or if you want to change your mind and convert what you did into something that undoes what is on origin, and changes it to what you have now, this will probably work

```
git reset origin/new_ci3
# now commit all local changes again and they will include undoing what is in your last commit, and the new solution
git push origin new_ci3 # no force push needed
```

---

actually check this out

```
git tag temp-change # save your commit in a
git reset --hard origin/new_ci3 # go back to where you were before you edited a public commit
git revert HEAD # now revert the commit instead of editing it
git cherry-pick temp-change # now apply the same change but after commit and revert
git diff temp-change # no diff to see it is the same end result
git push origin new_ci3 # no force push necessary
```

Comment: It's easier to follow this stuff though if you are looking at gitk or some other tree viewer before and after every step

Comment: also if anybody else has pushed to origin in the mean time, it gets a little more complicated